# Error retrieving the value in an enum class

Tags: java, android, kotlin, enums

in my application I want to create a very basic enum class, like this one:

```
enum class Week (val printableName: String) {
    MONDAY("Monday"),
    TUESDAY("Tuesday"),
    WEDNESDAY("Wednesday"),
    THURSDAY("Thursday"),
    FRIDAY("Friday"),
    SATURDAY("Saturday"),
    SUNDAY("Sunday")
}
```

and I want to retrieve the printablenName **from an activity in java**, not in kotlin.

I do it as follows:

```
String day = Week.FRIDAY.getPrintableName();
```

However, I always get the same error:

```
error: package Week does not exist
String color = Week.FRIDAY.getPrintableName();
```

What am I forgetting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the [full path](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html) from `root` of you project into the day or color field

```
String day = pathFromRoot.Week.FRIDAY.getPrintableName();
```

Comment: I am trying the proposed solution: String day = com.sergio.testapplication.Week.FRIDAY.getPrintableName(); but I get the same error. That is the full path, but I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

This actually not how you retrieve a getter function in Java. Please refer this: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#package-level-functions 
Basically you have to add your package name like packageName.Week.getPrintableName()